# subgradient calculus with dual problem

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

The following function has its origin in multicriteria optimization.

$$p(x)=\max\{1_n^{\top}(Cy-Cx): Cy \geq Cx, y \in X\},$$

where $C$ is a $p \times n$ matrix and $X$ is a convex polyhedral set, $\geq$ is meant in the pointwise sense and $1_n = (1,1,\ldots, 1)$.

It is a non-differentiable function. I read in an paper that to calculate a subgradient of this function, one writes first the dual of the problem and then calculates a subgradient of this dual. But since I'm not too familiar with convex analysis, I did not understand why we need the dual and is it possible to calculate directly?

Comment: What is $e$? It hasn't been defined.

Comment: e is the unit vector of R^p

Comment: Which unit vector?

Comment: e=(1,.., 1) in R^p

Comment: Oh ok. That's not actually a unit vector by the way, its norm isn't $1$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. What about my question, do you have any answer please

Comment: Can someone answer this question?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing $e$ to $1_n$, which is more common. I also defined some things for the sake of clarity.